# É um padrão os endereços SMTP do provedores de e-mail serem no padrão: smtp.provedor.com?

Tags: envio-de-email, smtp, javamail

> Pode existir algum provedor de e-mail que utilize um endereço **SMTP** que não inicie com **smtp.**?
>
> Ou existe alguma regra que não permite que sejam configurados servidores **SMTP** fora desse padrão.

Pois estou implementando um configurador de emails em meu projeto que permite que o usuário informe o endereço **SMTP** do provedor na mão por completo, sem nenhum tipo de validação na entrada do mesmo.

> Então gostaria de saber se posso criar algum tipo de pré-configuração, ou bloqueio que previna que o usuário entre com algo totalmente absurdo.

Pois fazendo alguns testes aqui com a biblioteca [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) (em uma versão um pouco mais lite, pois minha implementação é em android) fazendo tentativas de envio de e-mail utilizando um *host* do tipo: `gshshd.gdhfj.com`,  ele demora cerca de 3 minutos para retornar a `Exception` para minha aplicação, o que não é uma boa experiência para o usuário. Já se tento em um *host* do tipo: `smtp.gfdga.com`, ele retorna a `Exception` quase que instantaneamente para minha aplicação.

> Gostaria de talvez nem permitir host que não iniciam com **smtp.**, se isso for uma regra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, podem existir servidores de email que não utilizam `smtp.` como prefixo - `mail.` sendo um dos mais utilizados.

Se você deseja saber qual é o nome do servidor de email de um dado domínio, [consulte o registro MX do mesmo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record). O seguinte código Java (utilizando [dnsJava](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/)) pode lhe obter essa informação:

```
private Record[] lookupMxRecords(final String domainPart) throw TextParseException
{
    final Lookup dnsLookup = new Lookup(domainPart, Type.MX);
    return dnsLookup.run();
}
```

Comment: Mais existe um padrão, mesmo que seja: `smtp.` ou `.mail`, ou pode ser qualquer coisa, igual no exemplo que citei na pergunta?

Comment: Um padrão por uso, talvez - `smtp`, `mail` e similares são um exemplo. Padrão por especificação, não: um servidor chamado `patolino.looneytunes.com` pode ser uma entrada válida.

Comment: então em meu caso não posso fazer uma validação e nem restrição na entrada do usuário. O que posso tentar é verificar antes no **MX** conforme você citou.

Answer (score 3):

Eu creio que não seja um padrão, apenas uma prática convencional. Na [`RFC974`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc974) não impõe essa restrição enquanto ao endereço. :)

Answer (score 0):

O nome do subdomínio ou host é indiferente.
Apenas atente-se de configurar na zona DNS adequadamente como uma zona MX.